# How to use PowerShell to download a specific excel file from O365 SharePoint?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I am looking to use PowerShell to download an excel spreadsheet from my O365 SharePoint site. I have tried Invoke-Webrequest to the direct URL of the spreadsheet. I noticed that the spreadsheet was corrupted when I saved it as a .xlsx. I then converted the save file as a .txt file and it was showing this error. The excel file is not downloaded but is returning into an HTML.

```
<!-- Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" class="" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Sign in to your account</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

It seems that I need to sign to download the excel file. How would I go about that using PowerShell? See below the code I attempted with.

```
$url = "https://sharepoint.com/sites/Business/Shared%20Documents/Matt/PowerShell/business.xlsx"
$file = "C:\Users\admin\Documents\PowerShell\business.xlsx"
Invoke-Webrequest -URI $url -OutFile $file
```

Answer (score 0):

please try the below script in SharePoint Online Management Shell as an admin:

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://yourdomain-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential admin@yourdomain.onmicrosoft.com
Set-Location -Path "https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/yourlibrary"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/yourlibrary/yourfile.xlsx" -OutFile "C:\yourpath\yourfile.xlsx"
```